# Ranges on Rust wrapper types?

Tags: rust, range

Is it possible to use custom structs as ranges?

For example:

```rust
struct Wrap(u32);

fn main() {
    let x = Wrap(0);
    (x..).take(10);
}
```

gives me

```
1 | struct Wrap(u32);
  | ----------- doesn't satisfy `Wrap: Step`
```

And `Step` is an experimental API. Not possible in normal Rust, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `..` syntax uses [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html), which implements [iterator only if](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Iterator-for-Range%3CA%3E) the underlying type implements [Step](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Step.html), which in turn requires you to implement `Clone` and `PartialOrd`, and thus also `PartialEq`.

Possible, but implementing `Step` is currently nightly-only.

```rust
#![feature(step_trait)]

use std::iter;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct Wrap(u32);

// Forward implementation to underlying u32
impl iter::Step for Wrap {
    fn steps_between(start: &Self, end: &Self) -> Option<usize> {
        u32::steps_between(&start.0, &end.0)
    }

    fn forward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        u32::forward_checked(start.0, count).map(Wrap)
    }

    fn backward_checked(start: Self, count: usize) -> Option<Self> {
        u32::backward_checked(start.0, count).map(Wrap)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Wrap(0);
    let values = (x..).take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    assert_eq!(values, vec![Wrap(0), Wrap(1), Wrap(2), Wrap(3), Wrap(4), Wrap(5), Wrap(6), Wrap(7), Wrap(8), Wrap(9)]);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b6e3d578a553764cc30b766335c4d271)